# How do I choose a Google Storage bucket as a specific resource for a Cloud Run trigger?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

When I create a new Cloud Run trigger, I want to take the event **storage.objects.create** from a specific bucket. I have tried using:

- bucket-name.
- gs://bucket-name
- //storage.googleapis.com/projects/_/buckets/bucket-name

My code is working with the Any resource option but I only need to listen to one bucket.

[Cloud run trigger form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cst1a.png)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your Cloud Run service is being triggered by a [PubSub push](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/pubsub-push). To specify the bucket that will [notify](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes#enabling) the PubSub topic when a file is uploaded you can run:

`gsutil notification create -t TOPIC_NAME -f json gs://BUCKET_NAME`

Also here[[1]](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/pubsub-push) [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub) are some resources that explain all the full picture.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but my Cloud Run service is triggered by the event storage.objects.create as can be seen in the picture. There is no PubSub topic involved.

Comment: Hi, sorry I missunderstood, I believe that resourceName cannot be used to filter on specific buckets yet since eventarc it is still a beta release.

Comment: @llompalles Were you able to solve this issue? I am stuck in the same issue.